# Refactor maven block in gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on an android project, and have a number of custom repositories using the same credentials:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "<url1>"
    credentials {
      username = "<username>"
      password = "<password>"
    }
  }

  maven {
    url "<url2>"
    credentials {
      username = "<username>"
      password = "<password>"
    }
  }

}
```

Is there a way to define a method (block?) so that I can define the username and password once and not have to repeat it every time? I'd like to be able to do:

```
repositories {
  customMaven { url "<url1>"}
  customMaven { url "<url2>"}
}
```

Apologies if I'm using terms incorrectly here - gradle syntax is somewhat of a mystery to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First answer provided by @ToYonos will work fine, but if you are looking for a solution based on a *configuration block*, you can use the method `MavenArtifactRepository maven(Action<? super MavenArtifactRepository> action)` from [RepositoryHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html) class ([see here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler:maven(org.gradle.api.Action))), as follows:

```
// a Closure that builds an Action for configuring a MavenArtifactRepository instance
def customMavenRepo = { url ->
    return new Action<MavenArtifactRepository>() {
        void execute(MavenArtifactRepository repo) {
            repo.setUrl(url)
            repo.credentials(new Action<PasswordCredentials>() {
                void execute(PasswordCredentials credentials) {
                    credentials.setUsername("<username>")
                    credentials.setPassword("<password>")
                }
            });
        }
    };
}

// usage
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven customMavenRepo("http://company.com/repo1")
    maven customMavenRepo("http://company.com/repo2")
    maven customMavenRepo("http://company.com/repo3")
}
```

**EDIT** from comments below: solution will Closure would look as follow. I think the use of `curry` method (see [Currying closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_left_currying)) is needed here, but maybe there are other ways to simplify...

```
// one closure with URL as parameter
ext.myCustomMavenClosure = { pUrl ->
    url pUrl
    credentials {
        username = "<username>"
        password = "<password>"
    }
}
// helper function to return a "curried" closure
Closure myCustomMaven (url){
    return myCustomMavenClosure.curry(url)
}

repositories {
    // use closure directly
    maven myCustomMavenClosure.curry ("http://mycompany.com/repo1")
    // or use helper method
    maven myCustomMaven("http://mycompany.com/repo2")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's more or less what I was looking for, I just couldn't figure out the syntax. What's the meaning of `void execute`?

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Action.html :  `execute(T t)` method is the main and single method exposed by `Action<T>` interface, and it is  used to configure the given object on which the action applies. It's one  way to configure objects in Gradle , the other way is to used Closures

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to write what you did using closures?

Comment: Great answer. I really like that you showed how to use the Action, something i had been trying to setup in my plugins as I move away from groovy to java.

Answer (score 4):

Gradle is all about this kind of customization :

```
repositories {
    ['<url1>', '<url2>'].each { u ->
        maven {
            url u
            credentials {
                username = "<username>"
                password = "<password>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```