# In build.gradle how to extract and reuse Maven repository configuration?

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures, build.gradle

I've got this `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "$artifactory_user"
            password "$artifactory_password"
        }
        url 'http://some.domain/artifactory/repo'
    }
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "$artifactory_user"
                password "$artifactory_password"
            }
            url 'http://some.domain/artifactory/repo'
        }
    }
}
```

I want to extract and reuse the Maven repository definition.

This is not working:

```
repositories {
    mavenRepository()
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
        mavenRepository()
    }
}

private void mavenRepository() {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "$artifactory_user"
            password "$artifactory_password"
        }
        url 'http://some.domain/artifactory/repo'
    }
}
```

It results in

> Could not find method mavenRepository() for arguments [gradle-dev] on
>   repository container of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: see similar question with some solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617230/6899896

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refactor maven block in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610815/refactor-maven-block-in-gradle)

Answer (score 3):

lets say you have a separate repositories.gradle file and name your maven repo..

```
maven {
    name 'myrepo'
    url 'https://xxxx'
    credentials {
        username = System.getenv("xxx") ?: "${xxx}"
        password = System.getenv("xxx") ?: "${xxx}"
    }
}
maven { name 'anotherrepo' }
```

then at root project level you can run:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/repositories.gradle"
```

This will populate repositories with all repos. Then to use populate a specific one somehwere else, you can use:

```
repositories.add(rootProject.repositories.getByName('myrepo'))
```

I found the answer on this blog page: https://themightyprogrammer.dev/snippet/reusing-gradle-repo
thanks to mightprogrammer!